# C++ lnk2005 error on two files with extern "C", why?

Tags: c++, c++-cli, export, command-line-interface, lnk2005

I have a CPP with extern "C" functions. If they are all in a single file, everything works great. I want to split up the functions into different files just for organizational purpose.

So lets say I have these two files:

File_One.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "Functions.h"
#include "Variables.h"
#include <string>
#include "File_Two.cpp"

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void MethodOne()
    { 
        MethodTwo();
    }
}
```

File_Two.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "Functions.h"
#include "Variables.h"
#include <string>

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void MethodTwo()
    { 
    }
}
```

I have tried rearranging my include headers in different order, and even place no include headers in file_one.cpp other than the include for file_two.cpp but I always get the same errors.

1) error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

2) error LNK2005: _MethodTwo already defined in File_One.obj

What exactly am I doing wrong?
What should I do to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not usually a good thing to include one cpp file in another.  If you do so you need to make sure the included cpp file is not being compiled and linked.

Comment: I took your advice and built a header file and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running into issues because you're including the `File_two.cpp` file in your `File_one.cpp` file. What is happening is that `File_two.cpp` and `File_one.cpp` are getting compiled and linked. But because `File_two.cpp` is included in `File_one.cpp`, the linker is seeing two copies of `MethodTwo`, and can't decide which to use.

You should move the declarations to a header:

`File_one.h:`

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void MethodOne()
}
```

And include that instead.

`File_two.h:`

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void MethodTwo();
}
```

Then define the functions with their body in their respective `.cpp` files. No need for extern "C" in the source files.